# firebase/swift: retrieve value data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve all the true and false values within questions/06_26_2017/question1. The only way I have found to do that is to use the uid to get just the values. That will not work because I can not explicitly state every uid that is or will be. How do I get all the values under questions/06_26_2017/question1 in this format: [false, true]?

[image: Firebase Database Structure]

I store the true and false values by uid.

```
@IBAction func yes(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("questions").child(finishedDate).child("question1").child(uid!)

    answer = true

    ref.setValue(answer)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "1to2", sender: nil)

}

@IBAction func no(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("questions").child(finishedDate).child("question1").child(uid!)

    answer = false

    ref.setValue(answer)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "1to2", sender: nil)

}
```

Let me know if you need any more information or if I wasn't clear about what I need help with. Thanks for your time!

Comment: has my answer helped?

Comment: @VladPulichev yes, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("questions").child(finishedDate).child("question1")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Bool] {
        // your keys is uid's, values - true/false
    }
})
```

Hope it helps